# php ssh2 fgets();

Tags: php, ssh

im try to open a file on a remote host and read it, but i got a return value of 1.
Maybe anyone find my bug.

```
public function get()

        {
            return $stream = file_get_contents("ssh2.sftp".$this->connection."/home/user/logfile.txt");
        }
```

$this->connection is:

```
public function __construct($host , $port , $user , $pass )
{
    if(!$this->connection = ssh2_connect($host, $port)) return -1;
    if(ssh2_auth_password( $this->connection, $user, $pass )) return -1;
    return 1;
}
```

Connection works also, can send other commands like tar ...

Answer (score 1):

Might I recommend [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)?  It's easier to use and much better supported.  Here's how you'd do it with that:

```
<?php
$sftp = new Net_SFTP($host, $port);
if (!$sftp->login($user, $pass)) {
    exit('bad login');
}
echo $sftp->get('/home/user/logfile.txt');
?>
```

If you have problems with phpseclib you can create log files and post them on the official support forums and get top notch support there.